# In the corner were corralled a few old desks

Tags: inversion

> In the corner **were** corralled a few old desks.

Is it fine to put "were" in front? And why?
please give more examples to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In day-to-day English, this sentence would usually follow the pattern of subject–verb–object (SVO) to become

**A few old desks were corralled in the corner.**

However, your sentence (which is perfectly valid by the way) is an example of *inversion*, where the verb is placed *before* the subject.

Inversion is something we use every day when creating questions (are you hungry?), but in written English, it is a literary technique used for emphasis
or special effect, and it makes a sentence sound striking or unusual.

In written English, as well as in a very formal style, inversion can be used in the following cases :

**After negative adverbial expressions:**

- Under no circumstances can we accept credit cards.
- In no way can he be held responsible.
- At no time did she say she would come.
- Not until I heard my name did I believe I had won the race.

**After adverbial expressions of place:**

- Round the corner came the postman.
- On the doorstep was a bunch of flowers.

**After 'seldom', 'rarely', 'never', and 'little':**

- Seldom have I seen such a beautiful view.
- Rarely did he pay anyone a compliment.
- Never had I felt so happy.
- Little did he imagine how dangerous it would be.

**After 'hardly', 'scarcely', 'no sooner', when one thing happens after another.**

- Hardly had I begun to speak when I was interrupted.
- Scarcely had we started our meal when the phone rang.
- No sooner had I arrived than they all started to argue.

**After adverbial expressions beginning with 'only' and 'not only':**

- Only after the meeting did I realize the importance of the subject.
- Only when the plane landed safely did he calm down.
- Not only was the car slow, it was also very uncomfortable.

**After exclamations with 'here' and 'there':**

- Here comes the winner!
- There goes all our money!

More information can be found here:
http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/inversion.html

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for giving such a detailed explaination! Thank you !!!!

Comment: Erm, that's not quite right. It's not that the verb has been placed before the Subject in the OP's example, it's that the locative complement and the subject have swapped places (subject-dependent inversion). Almost of your other examples show something very different - subject auxiliary inversion. This isn't what happens in the OP's sentence. If it was we would get "In the corner were a few old desks coralled", or "Were a few old desks corralled in the corner." depending on whether the locative complement was fronted before the SAI took place :)